Ubuntu 24.04 server install on software raid1 ssds btrfs
what would be the best way to install ubuntu server 24.04 on mirrored software raid1 (two) ssds btrfs?
I found the tutorial below for 20.04, would 24.04 require different steps? Would 24.04 offer new features as far as the OS install on raid1 btrfs is concerned?
https://alexskra.com/blog/ubuntu-20-04-with-software-raid1-and-uefi/
Thank you, ioan

It seems it is still not possible to install Ubuntu server (24.04) on BTRFS RAID1. It is only possible mdadm RAID1 on BTRFS, which would reduce the BTRFS benefits. Please correct me if I'm wrong.
Thank you, ioan
